# Blacklist user based on device in Android firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing a chat app for android with Firebase backend. I have report function which I blacklist some users based on inappropriate behaviour. I am using `android_id` for blacklisting device instead of user account. Because permanent device Id's like IMEI, Serial Key is not available for android 10 and above. I want to know what is the best way to build a report and ban system for android.

Comment: It would a better idea to ban the *user*, not the *device*. Your app should have a login system that lets you disable user accounts as needed.

Comment: I have a login system. I can do it with user account ID. But what happens if user is a spammer and creates another account?

Comment: Then ban that account too. If they are serious, then they could also just create emulator instances indefinitely, or hack their device to fake whatever unique ID you think should be on it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, It is a semi-anonymous app, so I wanted to give users ability to use it anonymously, also. But in this case I'll create anonymous accounts using Firebase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the MAC address of the android phone which you want to banned and put it on the server, than at the login you can verify if the mac is in the db, else if you have a user system you can create a ban function

Comment: Based on [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) from Google, calling Wifi or Bluetooth Mac address returns `02:00:00:00:00:00` between android 6 and android 9.